# How to pass named arguments to a function invoked by Pandas transform?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using Pandas 1.2 I do not know how to pass extra named arguments (kwargs) to the function (np.std) invoked by `transform`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'box': ['a100','a100','a100','a200','a200','a300','a300','a300','a300'], 
    'price': [1.5, 3.2, 2.1, 3.3, 1.5, 3.2, 2.1, 3.3, 4.4]})

df['box_price_std'] = df.groupby('box').transform(np.std)

df['box_price_std_1'] = df.groupby('box').transform(np.std, ddfo=1)
```

This throws:

`TypeError: std() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ddfo'`

**Can you show me the correct syntax to pass named arguments, such as ddfo, to the standard deviation function using `transform`?**

Comment: The way you pass it is correct, however it's `ddof`, not `ddfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ddfo` with `ddof`(Delta Degrees of Freedom)!